# Zabbix jmx check availability

Tags: zabbix, zabbix-agent

Sometimes in my zabbix I see so my JMX agent is unavailable, if anyone knows a way to monitor the status of the JMX agent, whether it is possible ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to use a `nodata()` trigger on some JMX item, same as you would do with `agent.ping` or any other item to check that the data is coming.

Another would be to use internal item `zabbix[host,jmx,available]` (see [internal item documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.2/manual/config/items/itemtypes/internal)). If the value of this item is 1, then the JMX icon in the frontend is green. Otherwise, if the value is 0, then the JMX icon is red. Value 2 corresponds to the icon being grey.

If you are interested in monitoring the availability of the Java gateway itself, rather the JMX agent, a good idea would be to use internal item `zabbix[java,,ping]`. Unfortunately, according to [ZBX-8049](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBX-8049), it does not really work currently.